# Can this problem be represented as a second-order cone program?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

$LOU_{min} = \underset{(m_1,\dots,m_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n}{\text{min}}
 \sum_{i=1}^N - u_i\left(m_i\right)$

$ 0.1 \leq m_i - b_i < p_i \qquad \forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$

$p_i - m_i \leq rmax_i \qquad \forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$

$Q_{req} = \sum_{i=1}^N \left(p_i - m_i\right)$

$u_i(m_i) = {m_i}^{0.5}$ and in other cases ${m_i}^{0.4}$

Comment: The strict inequalities can’t be represented in SOCP you’ll have to specify a tolerance for strict inequality.

Comment: Thanks @BrianBorchers - so how can I specify this tolerance, please? How do you suggest this problem be represented then?

Comment: I can't answer that question- it depends on your underlying problem.  Is it OK as long as $m_{i}-b_{i} \geq 1.0e-300$?  What about $m_{i}-b_{i} \geq 0.1$?

Comment: @BrianBorchers $m_i - b_i \geq 0.1$ would be a reasonable choice, yes :)